# How should I import my own internal packages in go?

Tags: go, package

I'm trying to make a Go app using the (unoffical) [Standard Go Project Layout](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout). What I don't understand is how I should import the packages in the `internal` directory.

[This is my project](https://github.com/ComaVN/project-layout/tree/bcfb6365be08ecffd29b0cce5eb43e1cc6651ec1)

Using the Dockerfile, which copies the `internal` directory to the $GOPATH, it works:

```
~/go/src/project-layout$ docker build --no-cache .
(...)
Step 5/7 : RUN ls -la /go/src
 ---> Running in a27235b0bbef
total 24
drwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          4096 Apr 29 07:05 .
drwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          4096 Apr 12 22:23 ..
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     root           556 Apr 29 06:06 README.md
drwxrwxr-x    3 root     root          4096 Apr 29 06:08 app
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Apr 29 07:05 myproject
drwxrwxr-x    3 root     root          4096 Apr 29 06:11 pkg
Removing intermediate container a27235b0bbef
 ---> bb924f8f88f0
Step 6/7 : RUN go build -o myapp ./cmd/myapp/main.go
 ---> Running in 06bd6cd778d2
Removing intermediate container 06bd6cd778d2
 ---> 31184f9224c8
Step 7/7 : RUN ./myapp
 ---> Running in baf75d4dd503
Hello World, from myapp main
Hello world, from myapp internals
Hello world, from myprivatelib: 'myapp internal'
Hello world, from myprivatelib: 'myapp main'
Removing intermediate container baf75d4dd503
 ---> 5747b6b4686f
Successfully built 5747b6b4686f
```

However, when I try to build locally, I get:

```
~/go/src/project-layout$ go build -o myapp ./cmd/myapp/main.go
cmd/myapp/main.go:6:2: cannot find package "app/myapp" in any of:
    /home/comavn/go/src/project-layout/vendor/app/myapp (vendor tree)
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/app/myapp (from $GOROOT)
    /home/comavn/go/src/app/myapp (from $GOPATH)
cmd/myapp/main.go:7:2: cannot find package "pkg/myprivatelib" in any of:
    /home/comavn/go/src/project-layout/vendor/pkg/myprivatelib (vendor tree)
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/pkg/myprivatelib (from $GOROOT)
    /home/comavn/go/src/pkg/myprivatelib (from $GOPATH)
```

I can get it to work by symlinking `internal/app` and `internal/pkg` in the vendor directory, but that seems wrong...

So, what am I doing wrong here? How should I import these internal packages?

Comment: For a package to be able to import an internal package the internal one must live in a subfolder of the importing one, if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: The whole raison d'être of an _internal_ package is that it _cannot_ be imported from some arbitrary package but one from a package "higher up" in the file system layout.

Comment: @volker, I'm not trying to import it from some arbitrary package, I'm importing it from my main package. The idea being that `cmd/myapp/main.go` only has a tiny bit of boilerplate, and  all application logic is in `internal/app`

Comment: For Go the package cmd/myapp _is_ some arbitrary package and cannot import app/myapp because cmd/myapp is not a parent directory of app/myapp. The fact that you think that cmd/myapp is tightly related to app/myapp is o no concern to the go tooling. Stop fighting the tooling. You simply _cannot_ import internal packages from somehwere else.

Comment: @Volker are you suggesting that the (unoffical) Standard Go Project Layout is doing it wrong? What would your layout be? putting `internal` under `cmd/myapp`?

Comment: The "Standard Go Project Layout" is just one possible way and far from "standard" but I doubt it is wrong. The problem seems to stem from a misconception on how packages work (read "How to Write Go Code" as a real standard reference): It seems your package import path are _not_ the claimed "cmd/myapp" and "internal/app". A package import path is the full path ether below GOPATH/src or as declared in the go.mod. Just read How to Write Go Code and stick to that. No need to get fancy and no need to adopt some folder structure claimed "standard" by 1 person.

Comment: @Volker I haven't claimed anything about my package import path, nor am I fighting the tooling. I am merely a relative new go user, who is trying to figure out how to layout my projects, without reinventing the wheel. The first few google hits for "go project layout" all suggest the `cmd`/`internal` separation, which makes sense to me because I'd like to keep my `main` package small and simple.

Having tried and failed to get that to work, I put the question here. I have no stake in whatever layout.

"How to Write Go Code" says nothing about `go.mod`, I'll have to look into that.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found the proper solution: https://github.com/ComaVN/project-layout/commit/6415a8f06dd7fbdcf1c7282bc3ec172c3e145611

You have to import using the project name as well:

```golang
import (
    "project-layout/internal/app/myapp"
    "project-layout/internal/pkg/myprivatelib"
)
```

Unfortunatly, this does mean that the build depends on the exact directory name used for the project.

Comment: That is always true of Go projects. The project path is relevant to dependency resolution.

Comment: Why not making it a module, then the project's top directory doesn't matter anymore, if I'm not mistaken: the module name is set in the associated go.modvfile.